# Chinese characters showing as boxes in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, character-encoding

I just received a bunch of Chinese characters back from the localization people in Excel spreadsheet format. When I import the data into my SQL Server 2005 table (`nvarchar` columns) it displays as a bunch of boxes instead of the actual characters. I'm thinking this isn't right. Does anyone have an idea why it would be behaving this way?

EDIT: The data is still represented in the boxes somehow. When I load the data into my application and bind it to a UI element it displays correctly as Chinese. The issue I am having is that if I initiate a messagebox.show using the Chinese characters I still get the boxes and I can't help but think this is related to the boxes I am seeing in the DB.

Comment: font installation would be my guess.  Excel knows how to handle, but sql Server doesn't.

Comment: i was going to also suggest the font being used by SQM Server Management Studio. Perhaps try connecting Excel back to SQL Server data source and see if Excel displays them properly. (i.e. are they really wrong in SQL Server, or just the application you're using to select/display them). You also might try `SELECT UNICODE (TheColumn) FROM TheTable` to see if the unicode code point is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what front end you are using. Looks like Windows Application. The dialog box uses the system properties of the machine. It would be better to use Chinese Windows . As far as SQL Server shows you boxes here is the post which will give you the clue
[Japanese/Chinese language data in SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569845/japanese-chinese-language-data-in-sql-server-table)